# Simple Server-Client Input/Output

Tags: java, client-server

I am in the process of developing a very simple client-server program; however, I am a big believer in developing the code in portions (not coding everything and then running it), i.e.developing workable portions that function as expected. With what I thought would be a simple foray into to programming's more complex side, I thought I would try out a "proof of concept": I want my client to send a 'String' objext and the server to print the `String` object to the console (I have much more to do, but that seemed like a simple starting point).

I am running into an issue in that I can't even get my client or server to instantiate their Input/Output Streams and I am unsure why. It may be one of two problems:

1. I am an idiot and the reason is glaringly obviously.
2. For some reason, the server is not recognizing the client.

In this case, I have a feeling the answer is probably no. 1.

Here's are two code fragments from my client and server with some edits to make it more readable and understandable as to what is going on.

**SERVER**

```
try {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(commandlineArg);
    System.out.println("Waiting for clients to connect...");

    while (true) {
        clientConnection = serverSocket.accept();
        input = new ObjectInputStream(clientConnection.getInputStream());
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(clientConnection.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();

        File file = new File((String) input.readObject());
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

**CLIENT**

```
try {
    serverSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), portNo);
    input = new ObjectInputStream(serverSocket.getInputStream());
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(serverSocket.getOutputStream());

    output.writeObject(fileName);
    output.flush();
}
```

The port no. is correct supplied for both the client and server (and above the reserved range). Again, the trouble is that `input` and `output` are not instantiating. The program stops and will not continue past the attempt to connect; hence my belief that I am doing something incorrectly in the connection piece.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: You should read the documentation of the [`ObjectInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#ObjectInputStream(java.io.InputStream)) constructor (look for the work blocks). Then take a look at your client and think about its flow and what constructing the input stream on the client would do.